# need help on regex with comparision

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a small question in tcl regular expression,

my sample goes like this

"rollno" is a variable which is list of `10211 17311 15111 16111 10111`

`$rollno` takes a value at a time. for example `rollno = 10211`

```
student_1_class_A_Teacher = 10211
student_1_class_B_Teacher = 17311
student_1_class_c_Teacher = 15111
student_2_class_A_Teacher = 16111
student_2_class_B_Teacher = 10111
```

i need a regular expression which substitutes the variable "$rollno" in regular expression, and should return the classID = A

Comment: Sounds like homework for me. Too restricted: you have to use regexp, the regexp have to contain the no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you have the value '15111' and an input file:

```
student_1_class_A_Teacher = 10211
student_1_class_B_Teacher = 17311
student_1_class_c_Teacher = 15111
student_2_class_A_Teacher = 16111
student_2_class_B_Teacher = 10111
```

You want to return 'c'?

You could try something like this:

```
class_\w(?=_Teacher = 15111)
```

This will return 'class_c', then you can extract the last character to get 'c'.

Comment: But i need to give "$rollno" inside the regex and after this value getting substituted then it should extract value "c" according to you

Comment: the value is getting sustituted in regex but the regex showing no matches found

Comment: i tried this class_\w(?=_Teacher = $rollno) but its not working :(

Comment: @user2100556 - I don't know tcl, but I would imagine that you'd want to use something like `"_\w(?=_Teacher = " + $rollno + ")"` (look up string concatenation in tcl).

Comment: With Tcl, you use direct interpolation: `"class_\\w(?=_Teacher = $rollno)"` (the double backslash is because you want a single backslash in the RE, and it's also a general Tcl metacharacter).